# VBA NETComm issues

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, usb-drive, usbserial

I am working on a VBA GUI that I have not developped by myself.
I do not really know VBA langage and I need help.

I am trying to drive an electronique card plugged as USB with that GUI.
The problem is that I am trying to use NETComm.ocx to send instruction to the device but I have an issue that is knowed by the GUI developper and voluntary ignored because he does not have the issue. It seems to depend of the computer.

I am adding NETComm.ocx and MSComm32.ocx files to the path where Excel VBA is looking for them. When I check in the References panel, it seems to work well but when I am executing the code, I have a

> "Run-time error '424' : object required.

When I clic "Debug" it highlight the following line :

```
NETComm1.CommPort = VirtualCommPortNumber
```

VirtualCommPortNumber is an integer.
It seems like it does not know NETComm but I do not know how to do to fix that.

Thanks for your help.

Titouan

Comment: The error means `NETComm1` is Nothing, in other words the object could not be created and you're trying to access a property of something that doesn't exist.

Comment: Did you register the OCX files? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/146219/how-to-register-an-activex-control-ocx-manually

Comment: Thank you both for your answers.
@KostasK, I understood that but after all I tried, it still does not exist wheras it should ...
@braX That is something I tried but I can only unregister the file. It seems like I can not register it back ... When I am using the command : ``` Regsvr32 /i C:\Windows\System\NETComm.ocx ```, I got the following error : 
"The module ... was loaded but the entry-point Dll was not found." When I use a dll explorer there is a function named DllRegisterServer.
Do you know a solution to this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to Copy `NETComm.ocx` and `MSCOMM32.OCX` to C:\Windows\System
I think the Paths are hard-coded in these files, so they can be only registered from here.

Run `cmd` as administrator and

Type `regsvr32 C:\Windows\System\NETComm.ocx` and ENTER

Type `regsvr32 C:\Windows\System\MSCOMM32.OCX` and ENTER

Resource:
https://info.kmtronic.com/control-kmtronic-relays-via-excel.html